# Using @Slf4j Annotation from lombok, but still have error that method log is unknown

Tags: intellij-idea, slf4j, lombok

I have a very strange behaviour of Intellij.

I had a single project before, I converted it to a multi module pom and everything seemd to work.

But now I see in my sourcecode the error, that the method log is undefined in spite of the fact that I have annotated the class with @Slf4j from lombok.

And the strange thing is, that I'm able to compile and run the project and I see all the log messages. but I still see this error shown in IntelliJ.

Look at my screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRGto.png)

Comment: Have you tried to run "File | Invalidate Caches"?

Comment: Did you install the Lombok Plugin in IntelliJ?

Answer (score -1):

hmm, no unfortunatly deleting the cashes doesn't solve the problem.

But I finally solved it.

I have done two things (so I dont know if both were required ^^):

1. I activated the "enable the annotation processing"
2. I installed the Lombok Plug in and activated all options (Builder Support and so on

Comment: This is not an answer. Please consider to write a comment or update your question instead.